# Socket communication over internet Perl

Tags: perl, sockets, tcp

How can I make sockets work over the internet?

For a TCP server I have created a socket in local IP and I set up port forwarding from the router.

For the client I gave the router's IP address as `PeerAddr` (peer address). When starting the client from remote computer it's not working.
~Sorry, i am clear now and below is the snippet~ 
**UPDATED:**
Server Snippet:

```
$server_socket = new IO::Socket::INET (
                     LocalHost => '192.168.0.4',
                     LocalPort => '1080',
                     Proto     => 'tcp',
                     Listen    => 300,
                     Reuse     => 1,
                     Type      => SOCK_STREAM,
                 )
                   or die "ERROR in Socket Creation: $!\n";
```

Client Snippet:

```
my $socket = IO::Socket::INET->new (
                 PeerHost => '117.97.148.228',# router ip example
                 PeerPort => '1080',
                 Proto    => 'tcp',
             );
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What do you mean by 'Is not working'. Does it die? or just do nothing?

Comment: Throwing errors..  "Couldn't connect to remote_host:: The requested address is not valid in its context."

Comment: You are using ``LocalHost`` this means the local listening device. The error you are showing is related to the client

Comment: Stack Overflow uses the [*markdown*](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) syntax to format posts. Please use it in preference to HTML markup. Thanks.

Comment: I am new and i will rectify it hereaftr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely answer is that the router is not configured correctly yet.  If you are unsure about your perl code, then use a tool like netcat or telnet to test the connections locally and remotely.  I expect you will find that stock tcp tools cannot connect remotely either.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not running this code on the router itself, then the host/port you're attempting to connect to aren't "Local".  Try `PeerAddr` and `PeerPort` instead.

If that doesn't do the trick, we need more information.  At the very least, tell us *how* it fails.  Ideally, provide a brief but runnable self-contained example so that we can try it ourselves to see where things go wrong.

Also, as a side note, the use of indirect object notation (`new IO::Socket::INET`) is generally considered a deprecated practice.  Direct object notation (`IO::Socket::INET->new`) is the accepted current practice, as it avoids potential ambiguity and incorrect parsing by the perl binary.

Comment: U are right. Now i have updated my question, can u please suggest me now